# How can I set the render border from Python?

Tags: python, rendering, render-border

I'm trying to render 1px strips of images. Is there a way to set the render border in pixels?

I'm rendering a total image that is 1440x900 pixels. What I need to do is render it in vertical 1px strips. So 1440 images each 1x900 pixels.

I'm currently setting the border min and border max with python as follows:

```
render.border_min_x = i/1440
render.border_max_x = (i+1)/1440
render.border_min_y = 1
render.border_max_y = 900
```

It works okay but I'm finding that the output files vary in dimensions some are 1px some 2px and others 0px (which makes the script crash)

Is python limiting the number of decimal places and that is why the 0.0 - 1.0 scale isn't as accurate as I need.

Any help or work-around?

Comment: What for? Could simply splitting it after the render work, or are you trying to optimise renders by splitting the thing between many computers / threads / somethings?

Comment: It might be easier to render full resolution and split the image with Imagemagick or similar. (http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/)
You could write a python script to output each row.

Comment: @akupresanin , `border_min/max_x/y` should range between 0.0 and 1.0 too. I think your `min_y = 1` and `max_y = 900` are typos ?